# AFNetworking JSON-RPC Expected content type - Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain

Tags: objective-c, json, afnetworking, json-rpc

I'm using [this JSON-RPC client](https://github.com/wiistriker/AFNetwork-JSON-RPC-Client) that is based on AFNetworking

After making this call:

```
    AFJSONRPCClient *client = [[AFJSONRPCClient alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kAPIHost]];


[client invokeMethod:@"auth.login"
      withParameters:params
                 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

                     //success handling
                     completionBlock(responseObject);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    //error handling
    NSLog(@"error: %@", [error description]);
}];
```

I'm getting this in the NSLog for error:

> error: Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Expected content type {(
>       "text/json",
>       "application/json",
>       "text/javascript"
>   )}, got application/json-rpc" UserInfo=0xd02f680 **{NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion={"error": null, "jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": "1", "result": {"key": "38c491c894aa057d532e8b314d", "success": true}}**, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=, NSErrorFailingURLKey=someurl, NSLocalizedDescription=Expected content type {(
>       "text/json",
>       "application/json",
>       "text/javascript"
>   )}, got application/json-rpc, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=http://rpc.development.hotelzilla.net/>}

What I also don't understand is why the response is appearing with all the correct data (highlighted in bold).

So far, this is what I tried:

```
        [AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"application/json-rpc"]];

    // Accept HTTP Header; see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1
    [self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json-rpc"];

    [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first attempted solution of `[AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"application/json-rpc"]];` probably would have worked if you were having this issue with just `AFJSONRequestionOperation` but since you are using this client that isn't a subclass of `AFHTTPRequestOperation` so it doesn't respond to this method.

That might be a viable solution if you alter the code of the client you are using. In the source code an `AFJSONRequestOperation` called `operation` is created, if you attempted to use `[AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"application/json-rpc"]];` somewhere around here, you may be able to fix the issue.

Comment: Worked like a charm! I added that line to the init method in this client.
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Chompas I submitted this as an issue on the Github project and the owner just fixed it. [Source](https://github.com/wiistriker/AFNetwork-JSON-RPC-Client/blob/master/AFJSONRPCClient.m#L65)